# Submitted values are null when using @Named @ViewScoped

Tags: jsf-2

I have a problem with `@ViewScoped` Bean. When firing the method, the bean raises an `NullPointerException`.
    But the same works with  `@RequestScoped` and `@SessionScoped` Beans.
    Here is my code:

control.xhtml

```
   <h:form id="form1" >
               <p:growl id="messages" />
         <h:outputText value="Numero de Compte :" />  
  <p:inputText   id="txtCompte" value="#{controlBean.numeroCompte}" /> &nbsp; 
 <p:commandButton value="RECHERCHER" ajax="false" action="#{controlBean.rechercheCompte}"/>

                </h:form>
```

The Bean ControlBean :

```
@Named(value = "controlBean")
    @ViewScoped
    public class ControlBean extends Controller implements Serializable {
  private String numeroCompte;


        public String rechercheCompte() {

                if (numeroCompte!=null) {
                    System.out.println("Enter rechercheCompte "+numeroCompte);


                } else if (numeroCompte==null){
                      System.out.println("Enter rechercheCompte ; numcompte is null ");
                }

                return null;
            }

    }
```

the value of the variable `numeroCompte` is always null ;but with RequestScoped and SessionScoped Beans, we have the value from the interface.

Comment: CDI and the viewScope don't work together. Use a JSF managed bean for the view scope. Change `@Named` to `@ManagedBean`.

Comment: If you want everything to be CDI, use @ConversationScoped instead of ViewScoped.

Comment: Thanks for replying;will try it

Comment: That should be answered and closed!

Comment: Where shall I close it @Alexandre Lavoie?

Comment: @bouikstefan Create an answer and mark it as answered! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with the Help of all of you.
To use the @ViewScoped, the bean (in jsf2.1) need to be @ManagedBean annoted, not an CDI Bean.
So, the best way to doo it is :

```
@ManagedBean(value = "controlBean")
    @ViewScoped
    public class ControlBean extends Controller implements Serializable {
  private String numeroCompte;


        public String rechercheCompte() {

                if (numeroCompte!=null) {
                    System.out.println("Enter rechercheCompte "+numeroCompte);


                } else if (numeroCompte==null){
                      System.out.println("Enter rechercheCompte ; numcompte is null ");
                }

                return null;
            }

    }
```

Thanks :)

Comment: At least, put the solution in it!